# Force an HTTPS connection with BOTTLE.PY using MOD_WSGI via Apache?

Tags: python, https, bottle

I'm trying to force an HTTPS connection using BOTTLE.PY and Apache.  HTTPS works well, I just need to ensure a client connects via SSL.  Is there a way to force this behavior?  Preferably I'd like the browser to redirect to an equiv. HTTPS conn. if an HTTP conn. is attempted.

Comment: My web provider won't let me modify mod_rewrite modules.  Is there another way?  Perhaps via code in Python?  I was also hoping to avoid .htaccess for redirects too due to performance degradation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://your_server.com/$1
```

(In either a `.htaccess` or in the Apache configuration files.)

An alternative `RewriteCond` that you might also be able to use is...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
```